# Match and report similarly arranged set of cells in ms excel worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a set of cells like : Each alphabet is in seperate cell

A B C D E F

D E F G H D

H J E R T U

X Y M N N O

There are around 2000 to 3000 rows like this.

In same worksheet, this set has matches, or more like approximate matches. Matches in this case means , cells are identically arranged and they match with each other. For example

A B C **D** **E** F

**D** **E** F G **H** **D**

**H** J **E** R T U

X Y M **N N** O

somwhere down in same sheet  a set is like this

T B N D E F

D E Q Y H D

H J E R T U

X L M N N R

But it is observed that some cells are arranged in identical manner to the first given example set. like

T B N **D** **E** F

**D E** Q Y **H D**

**H** J **E** R T U

X L M **N N** R

Though surrounding sets are not as the same, some cells match exactly / similarly as
the first set. I need to identify them... Any one has clue about how it can be done ???

Are these called patterns ? or is there a reference so that similar reference material can be found on the internets ???

Comment: What value does the cell hold on your actual data, is it single alphabets or words?

Comment: it holds numbers 00-99

Comment: i tried with AND , but firstly i need to identify the pattern, then find it. Is there any way such repeating types of ones can be identified??

Comment: Are the cells being compared always a 6x4 section? Like A1:D6 compared to E1:H6, etc.

Comment: JNevill No. Its a 6 X 2200 grid. My focus to is identify a pattern which is repeating. I have the best way, if we can compare a given 50X6 or a 100x6 grid with above cells in table . . .The table can also be laid in vertical if needed if distance between likely cells can be calculated.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the entire excel sheet
2. Then Go to 'Menu Bar', and select Conditional Formatting > Highlight Cells Rules(From DropDown) > Select 'Text That Contains'
3. Enter the text that you want to highlight, and press OK
4. It will highlight the text in the entire excel sheet
5. Repeat step 1 to 4, if you want to highlight any other text (You can choose different color also for different texts)